# How to enable access control on mongos

Tags: mongodb, authentication, replicaset

I've tried to start my mongos instance with access control using the --auth option but I get `Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--auth'`. How do I require authentication to connect to the mongos instance?

Comment: [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/index.html) is for connecting to a sharded cluster from an application / client. From the operating system command prompt if you type the following you will see all the available options: `mongos --help`

Comment: You should ask your question only here or at dba.stackexchange.com. If you don't get an answer at one site, you can try the other one.